# Unwanted chars written from java REST-API to HadoopDFS using FSDataOutputStream

Tags: java, special-characters, hdfs, dataoutputstream

We built a java REST-API to receive event data (like click on a buy button) and write that data to HDFS.
Essentially we open streams for every host that is sending data (in JSON) or use existing ones, enrich data with a timestamp, an event name and hostname and write it into (FS)DataOutputStream:

```
1 public synchronized void writeToFile(String filename, String hostname, String content) throws IOException {
2    FSDataOutputStream stream = registry.getStream(filename, hostname);
3    stream.writeBytes(content);
4    stream.hflush();
5  }
```

First, we used `stream.writeChars(content)` in line 3, resulting in files like:
`.{.".m.e.s.s.a.g.e.".:.".h.e.l.l.o.".}`
Looking into the implementation of DataOutputStream.writeChars(String s), you see an 8-bit shift to the right and adding a leading x00 for every char, for reasons i don't understand.

Then I tried `stream.writeUTF(content)` in line 3, files looked much better:
`.W{"message":"hello"}`
But still, a few bytes to many. Looking into the code, writeUTF(String s) sends the number of bytes in s first, and then the string itself. So `.W` represents the number of bytes in the event data, proven when varying the length of the event data showed different leading chars in the file.

So my last resort, `stream.writeBytes(content)`. Here everything looked fine:
`{"message":"hello"}` until special characters came into play:
`{"message":"hallöchen"}` became `{"message":"hall.chen"}`. writeBytes cuts the leading 8 bits of the character before writing it. I think I need some UTF-8 functionality to write these chars correctly.

So, now I'm kind of lost. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1):

When I read this: [Why does DataOutputStream.writeUTF() add additional 2 bytes at the beginning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630242/why-does-dataoutputstream-writeutf-add-additional-2-bytes-at-the-beginning?rq=1) i felt like the mentioned FSDataOutputStream methods will not work for this. 
A quick (and maybe dirty) solution is this:

```
3 byte[] contentAsBytes = content.getBytes("UTF-8");
4 for (byte singleByte : contentAsBytes) {
5   stream.writeByte(singleByte);
6 }
```

A cleaner way would be not to use the FSDataOutputStream, but I couldn't find an alternative.
Any hint is still appreciated.

Comment: stream.write(contentAsBytes, 0, contentAsBytes.length); can replace your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping the FSDataOutputStream in a java.io.PrintStream and using its print methods. It is a long shot but let me know if that works for you.