# Java > PHP Socket - trash at start of message

Tags: java, php, sockets

I have a java server communicating with a PHP script called from apache. I am aiming to send a JSON from the java server to the php client when requested, however there is some stuff getting prefixed when its received on the client.

JAVA

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (socket.getInputStream()));                  
out= new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

//The server receives a JSON from the PHP script and replies. It recives and converts to a Gson JSON no problem.

String reply = "{\"status\":\"reg\",\"token\":\""+client.getToken()+"\"}\r\n";
//reply = "HELLO\r";
out.writeUTF(reply);
```

PHP

```
$rec = socket_read($socket, 2048,PHP_NORMAL_READ);
echo "Receiving... ";
echo $rec;
```

The issue is that the message received is pre-fixed with some crap.

Output From PHP

> Receiving...  1{"status":"reg","token":"QOPIPCNDI4K97QP0NAQF"}

If I send "HELLO\r"

> Receiving...   >HELLO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `DataOutputStream.writeUTF()` unless you are using `DataOutputStream.readUTF()` to read the message.

Here is a snippet of the javadoc of `writeUTF()`:

> Writes a string to the underlying output stream using modified UTF-8
>   encoding in a machine-independent manner.
>
> **First, two bytes are written to the output stream as if by the
>   writeShort method giving the number of bytes to follow**. This value is
>   the number of bytes actually written out, not the length of the
>   string. Following the length, each character of the string is output,
>   in sequence, using the modified UTF-8 encoding for the character. If
>   no exception is thrown, the counter written is incremented by the
>   total number of bytes written to the output stream. This will be at
>   least two plus the length of str, and at most two plus thrice the
>   length of str.

The bolded part above may tell you why you are getting weird characters at the beginning of your message.

Here is a workaround I believe will work in your case

```
BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
out.write(os.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

---

Reference: [Why does DataOutputStream.writeUTF() add additional 2 bytes at the beginning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630242/why-does-dataoutputstream-writeutf-add-additional-2-bytes-at-the-beginning?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks out.write(reply.getBytes()); sorted it.